# Update function on click

Tags: javascript

I want to call a function which I call currently with each page-load ALSO with a click of the element `#call-button`. This is my current function:

```
window.addEventListener("load", function() {}
```

I hope a wrong solution clarifies a bit what I mean. So I am asking how to do that one here correctly:

```
window.addEventListener("load" || "#call-button.click" , function() {}
```

Comment: First, your question is unclear. Second, If you have referred any post, it would be better to link them

Comment: Please formulate you're question correctly it's unclear what you're asking here !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function isn't defined, it is bounded to the event.

You can either do a click listener on your element and copy the function part, or you can create the function and both your listeners will call the function.

Comment: Could you maybe guide me a bit more within one of these solutions?

Comment: `document.getElementById('call-button').addEventListener('click', function() {
    var randomIndex = Math.ceil((Math.random() * 10) % randomStrings.length - 1);
    newText1 = randomStrings[randomIndex];
    newText2 = randomStrings2[randomIndex];
    $(function gruesse_type() {
        $("#random_mantra").typed({
            strings: [newText1],
            typeSpeed: 0
        });
    });
    answer2.innerHTML = newText2;
});`

Answer (score 3):

One way of doing it is bind the function to click of the element. And on window load `trigger` the element's click

```js
document.getElementById('call-button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  alert('Called!!!');
});

function onLoad(){
  document.getElementById('call-button').click();
}
```

```html
<body onload="onLoad()">
<button id="call-button">Click Me</button>
</body>
```

Comment: So, that solution would mean I keep my current thing and copy my functions' content within the part where you call the 'Called'-alert?

Comment: Yes. This wont be the best approach. But it will work.